# Ajax, error ajax me agrega elementos a la url

Tags: ajax, url, vb6

Estoy trabajando con Visual Basic y estoy queriendo implementar Ajax, el proceso de Ajax a veces me funciona cuando el parámetro que mando no tiene "-" ni "_", extrañamente, intento enviar un parámetro que contenga esos símbolos me genera error a pesar de que le haga un replace, al revisar el url que se genera; se puede ver que al final se agregó un segmento de información que es el que genera el problema.

Les agradecería muchísimo que me den ideas de que es lo que puede estar pasando.

El Ajax:

```
   function GetAccesoriosDB() {
    debugger
    var placa = document.getElementById('txtpla_veh').value;
    placa = placa.replace("-", "MEDIOXXXZ8");
    placa = placa.replace("_", "BAJOXXXZ8");
    
    var table = $('#tablaAccesoriosVehei').DataTable(
        {
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": 5,
                    "width": 10,
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return "<button type='button' onclick=eliminarAccesorio('" + row.Codigo + "') class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'> </button>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 4,
                    "width": 10,
                    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                        return "<button type='button' onclick=borrarAccesorio('" + row.Codigo + "') class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle'> </button>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 0,
                    "width": 50,
                },
                {
                    "targets": 3,
                    "width": 50,
                },
                {
                    "targets": 2,
                    "width": 100,
                }
            ],
            "language": {},
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": false,
            "destroy": true,
            "searching": false,
            "deferRender": true,
            "ajax":
            {
                "url": "frmVehiculos.aspx/GetAccesoriosDB",
                "contentType": "application/json",
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": "JSON",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.placa = placa
                },
                "dataSrc": function (json) {
                    
                    var return_data = json;
                    return return_data.listaAccesorios;
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "Codigo" },
                { "data": "Descripcion" },
                { "data": "Precio" },
                { "data": "Cantidad" }
            ]
        });
}
```

El error que muestra Google

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La url que genera error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que encerré en el cuadro rojo no debería ir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por tu respuesta. Igualmente quiero compartirle la solucion que le dí al problema.

yo estaba recibiendo el parametro de esta forma...

```
Public Shared Function GetAccesoriosDB(ByVal placa As String) As Object
```

lo que hice fue capturar el parametro de la siguiente forma y ya me funciono correctamente.

```
    Public Shared Function GetAccesoriosDB() As Object

    Dim placa = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("placa")
```

Saludos ♣

Answer (score 1):

Sucede porque el tipo de envió que utilizas es GET

```
"type": "GET"
```

Remplázalo por

```
"type": "POST"
```